# NFS /usr/share breaks Policykit beause of inotify support

Tags: linux, nfs, dbus, inotify

I just tried moving some files including `/usr/share` to a NFS partition to save space when running many similar virtual machines. The configuration mostly works except when starting services

I think this is why

```
$> systemctl status dbus -l
...
Cannot setup inotify for `/usr/share/dbus1/...
```

NFS does not support inotify.

I guess could move `/usr/share/dbus` out of the share and softlink it back in, but I'm wondering if there are any gotchas theree -- is that the best approach or should I fix this another way?