# Can't start services, probably policykit error

Tags: linux, nfs, dbus, systemctl, policykit

I can't restart services as root on CentOS.

```
Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

The `polkit` service isn't starting at boot.

```
$> systemctl status polkit
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:polkit(8)
```

If I try to start it manually:

```
$> systemctl status polkit
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-12-07 11:15:26 GMT; 2s ago
     Docs: man:polkit(8)
 Main PID: 2079 (polkitd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/polkit.service
           └─2079 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug

Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Started polkitd version 0.112
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Error opening rules directory: Error opening directory '/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d': Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 2 rules
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
Dec 07 11:15:26 sk-generic polkitd[2079]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
```

That `permission denied` error is suspicious (nevertheless the service seems to be running).

```
$> ls -l /usr/share/ | grep polkit-1
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root      root         25 Dec  7 11:04 polkit-1 -> /usr/share.local/polkit-1
$> ls -l /usr/share.local/ | grep polkit-1
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root      root      34 Jun  9  2014 polkit-1
$> ls -l /usr/share.local/polkit-1/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root 4096 Dec  7 10:53 actions
drwx------. 2 polkitd root    6 Jun  9  2014 rules.d
```

I have moved `/usr/share` and a few other post-initial-installation files to a NFS share. Yet the above permissions seem to be correct and `/usr/share/polkit-1` is a symlink to a directory on the *local* filesystem.

Now if do something like this:

```
$> service network restart
```

the virtual machine network icon flashes for a moment but then the whole machine locks up completely. `systemctl restart network` fails the same way.

My [original theory](https://superuser.com/questions/1153852/nfs-usr-share-breaks-policykit-beause-of-inotify-support) was that dbus was failing because inotify is not supported on NFS.

```
$> systemctl status dbus -l
...
Cannot setup inotify for `/usr/share/dbus-1/...
```

I then moved `/usr/share/dbus-1` back to the local filesystem (via soft link) and rebooted, `systemctl status dbus -l` seems to say everything's fine, up until I run `service network restart` at which point the whole machine locks up with a policykit error. I moved `/usr/share/polkit-1` to the local filesystem and that brings us to here.

What's wrong with policykit? Or rather, why can't services start?

Comment: What would that error be when it locks up?

Comment: Have you left SELinux enabled? Are there SELinux errors in the logs?